# Labview: incrementing duty cycle signal from serial port @1Hz

Tags: time, frequency, labview

To perform a hysteresis test on a part we need to activate the motor once per second with a duty cycle which increments with every cycle.

The NIDaq cards I have available are too old to be used as an arbitrary wave generator, so I need to use the serial port as the output to activate a mosfet circuit. Every second (every cycle @ 1Hz) the duty cycle needs to increment 1% from 0% to 100%

I've created programs which adjust the duty cycle as described and output to the serial port,  but the frequency is far to slow. We need 1hz but the labview cycle takes over 6 seconds for one increment and one rising edge.

Is there a way to send this 1hz signal, on time, to the serial port output buffer programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean you want to send a serial command to some sort of serial interfaced digital output module, or are you trying to manipulate one of the serial output lines directly to use as a digital output?

Comment: the later, use the serial line as digital output.

Comment: Have you not tried software timed writes to your DAQ card? In a loop with a 1 s cycle time (using Wait(ms) or a Timed Loop structure) set the DO line high, then Wait(ms) for the required time, then set it low again - control the execution flow using error wires and/or a sequence structure. I don't see why this should be any worse than your serial port idea. Neither of these is guaranteed to give you completely accurate timing on a non-real-time OS, but it should work OK most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this it seems to work:

[image]

any other ideas?

Comment: Well that's certainly inventive. Which serial line are you using as your output  - I assume one of the handshaking lines, rather than TXD?

Comment: Im sending it to a MAX232E ic where it will derive a digital signal and output to a mosfet gate. I've since modified the above program by changing the string constants to hex 00 and an empty space constant.